# Arduino XOR BCC checksum

Tags: arduino

I need to calculate the Block Check Character ([BCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_check_character)) via XOR of this array

```
byte data[] = {0x02,0x06,0x06,0x06,0x06,0x06};
```

and i'm under Arduino. Is there already any method out of the box to accomplish this?
Thank you

Comment: What does BCC stand for?

Comment: Just means Block Check Character, or checksum.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what BCC is, so I'll just assume you want the XOR of the array. If this data is *constant*, you can just calculate the XOR once and make it a constant too:

```
// 0x02 ^ 0x06 ^ 0x06 ^ 0x06 ^ 0x06 ^ 0x06 = 0x04
byte result = 0x04
```

Otherwise, you have to do this with variables:

```
byte result = data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[2] ^ data[3] ^ data[4] ^ data[5];
```